# Switching to UI context in coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I'm new to coroutines and I'm wondering if it's possible to switch from coroutineScope (GlobalScope) to UI scope for the code below. My problem is that the steps inside the coroutine launch body must be executed in a worker thread, otherwise the listener notification must be executed in the ui thread in order to avoid to call runOnUiThread in my activity code.

```kotlin
override suspend fun startRent(name: String, bikeMode: BikeMode, listener: StartRentListener) {
        var bleDevice : RxBleDevice
        val scanFilter: ScanFilter = ScanFilter.Builder().setDeviceName(name).build()
        val scanSettings: ScanSettings = ScanSettings.Builder().build()

        val job = GlobalScope.launch {
            try {
                bleDevice = rxBleClient.scanBleDevicesExt(rxBleClient, scanSettings, scanFilter)
                val bleConnection = bleDevice.establishConnectionExt()
                // write handshake
                connectionManager.writeHandshake(bleDevice, bleConnection)
                // open lock
                openLock(bleDevice, bikeMode, bleConnection)
                // getting user position
                apiHelper.sendLockRequest(bleDevice.name, getPosition())
                bleDevice.disconnect()
                // this should be called on main thread once all the previous operations are finished
                listener.onSuccess()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                listener.onError(e)
            }
        }
        job.join()
    }
```

A snippet of my current activity code:

```kotlin
bikeAccessClient.startRent(bikeBLEName, BikeMode.HYBRID, object :
                    StartRentListener {
                    override fun onSuccess() {
                        runOnUiThread {
                            // UI update here
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: The purpose of Coroutines is to get rid of callbacks. I'd suggest you to get rid of `listener: StartRentListener`

Comment: See [kotlinx.coroutines ui guide](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/ui/coroutines-guide-ui.md).

Comment: @Sergey, I know but how to notify ui if an error occurs in the procedure? Am i supposed to use Deferred?

Comment: @Pawel, thanks, I will

Comment: try to use `withContext(Dispatchers.Main) { listener.onSuccess() }`. Also `GlobalScope` is not recommended to use. You need to use local scope.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may use `withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {..}` function to execute a part of your code with the other Coroutine Dispatcher.

`kotlinx.coroutines.android` contains the definition of the `Dispatchers.Main` function and it integrates correctly with Android UI.

Using explicit Dispatcher in your code is quite error-prone. Instead, I would recommend designing the code with fewer explicit requirements.

I would wrote something like that:

```
fun uiActionHandlerToStartTheProcess() {
  launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
     val result = startRent(...) // no callback here, suspend function
     
     //UI Update Here
   }
}
suspend fun CoroutineScope.startRent() : SomeResultOfWork {
   //that function offloads the execution to a IO (aka brackground) thread
   return withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
     //here goes your code from `startRent`
     //use `suspendCancellableCoroutine {cont -> .. }` if you need to handle callbacks from it
    
     SomeResultOfWork()
   }
```

The code in the `launch(Dispatchers.Main){..}` block is executed in the UI thread. The call to `startRent` suspend function suspends the execution in the UI thread. Once the `startRent` is ready with the reply (from a background thread) it resumes the execution (which is done by the `Dispatchers.Main` and equivalent to the `runOnUiThread {...}`) and executes the UI update from the right thread

Comment: Thanks a lot Eugene, this is surely a better approach :)

Comment: `Dispatchers.UI` doesn't exist (or maybe it does, but deprecated), it's `Dispatchers.Main`.

Comment: That is the library 
https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/ui/kotlinx-coroutines-android/README.md
It is named `Dispatchers.Main`, sorry